# Stream de-duplication on Dataflow | Running services on Dataflow services

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to de-dupe a stream of data based on an ID in a windowed fashion. The stream we receive has  and we want to remove data with matching  within N-hour time windows. A straight-forward approach is to use an external key-store (BigTable or something similar) where we look-up for keys and write if required but our qps is extremely large making maintaining such a service pretty hard. The alternative approach I came up with was to groupBy  within a timewindow so that all data for a user within a time-window falls within the same group and then, in each group, we use a separate key-store service where we look up for duplicates by the  key. So, I have a few questions about this approach

[1] If I run a groupBy transform, is there any guarantee that each group will be processed in the same slave? If guaranteed, we can group by the userid and then within each group compare the sessionid for each user

[2] If it is feasible, my next question is to whether we can run such other services in each of the slave machines that run the job - in the example above, I would like to have a local Redis running which can then be used by each group to look up or write an ID too.

The idea seems off what Dataflow is supposed to do but I believe such use cases should be common - so if there is a better model to approach this problem, I am looking forward to that too. We essentially want to avoid external lookups as much as possible given the amount of data we have.

Answer (score 2):

1) In the Dataflow model, there is no guarantee that the same machine will see all the groups across windows for the key. Imagine that a VM dies or new VMs are added and work is split across them for scaling.

2) Your welcome to run other services on the Dataflow VMs since they are general purpose but note that you will have to contend with resource requirements of the other applications on the host potentially causing out of memory issues.

Note that you may want to take a look at [RemoveDuplicates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/RemoveDuplicates.java) and use that if it fits your usecase.

It also seems like you might want to be using [session windows](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/Sessions.java) to dedupe elements. You would call:

```
PCollection<T> pc = ...;
PCollection<T> windowed_pc = pc.apply(
    Window<T>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(N hours))));
```

Each new element will keep extending the length of the window so it won't close until the gap closes. If you also apply an AfterCount speculative trigger of 1 with an AfterWatermark trigger on a downstream GroupByKey. The trigger would fire as soon as it could which would be once it has seen at least one element and then once more when the session closes. After the GroupByKey you would have a DoFn that filters out an element which isn't an early firing based upon the pane information ([[3](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn.java#L283)], [[4](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/PaneInfo.java#L106)]).

```
DoFn(T -> KV<session key, T>)
         |
        \|/
Window.into(Session window)
         |
        \|/
Group by key
         |
        \|/
DoFn(Filter based upon pane information)
```

It is sort of unclear from your description, can you provide more details?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess I missed the RemoveDuplicates part since it is pretty much what I wanted. My problem was pretty much about removing duplicate data which can be identified by the session key although I am worried about two things - the duration of the session since duplicate data might be pretty late and also the cardinality of the groups themselves since we might have quite a few users creating as many groups. I am not exactly familiar with the triggering models you have mentioned here but those seem good starters. I can take a look and get back to you on this.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not being clear. I gave the setup you mentioned a try, except for the early and late firings part, and it is working on smaller samples. I have a couple of follow up questions, related to scaling this up. Also, I was hoping I could give you more information on what the exact scenario is.

So, we have incoming data stream, each item of which can be uniquely identified by their  fields. We also know that duplicates occur pretty far apart and for now, we care about those within a 6 hour window. And regarding the volume of data, we have atleast 100K events every second, which span across a million different users - so within this 6 hour window, we could get a few billion events into the pipeline.

Given this background, my questions are
[1] For the sessioning to happen by key, I should run it on something like

```
PCollection<KV<key, T>> windowed_pc = pc.apply(
        Window<KV<key,T>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(6 hours))));
```

where `key` is a combination of the 3 ids I had mentioned earlier. Based on the definition of Sessions, only if I run it on this KV would I be able to manage sessions per-key. This would mean that Dataflow would have too many open sessions at any given time waiting for them to close and I was worried if it would scale or I would run into any bottle-necks.

[2] Once I perform Sessioning as above, I have already removed the duplicates based on the firings since I will only care about the first firing in each session which already destroys duplicates. I no longer need the `RemoveDuplicates` transform which I found was a combination of (WithKeys, Combine.PerKey, Values) transforms in order, essentially performing the same operation. Is this the right assumption to make?

[3] If the solution in [1] going to be a problem, the alternative is to reduce the `key` for sessioning to be just `user-id, session-id` ignoring the `sequence-id` and then, running a `RemoveDuplicates` on top of each resulting window by `sequence-id`. This might reduce the number of open sessions but still would leave a lot of open sessions (#users * #sessions per user) which can easily run into millions. FWIW, I dont think we can session only by `user-id` since then the session might never close as different sessions for same user could keep coming in and also determining the session gap in this scenario becomes infeasible.

Hope my problem is a little more clear this time. Please let me know any of my approaches make the best use of Dataflow or if I am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: [1] Dataflow currently distributes key ranges of work across machines, so the number of keys scales with the number of machines. I would go with this approach and sync back with us with a job id if your having issues. [2] You are correct, RemoveDuplicates will not be needed since you will already be filtering for the first trigger firing. [3] This will also work but you'll have to wait 6 hours after there are no more events for the (user-id, session-id) key. Is it important to get the early firings?

Comment: Glad to know that it could possibly scale - I will try this out then. As for early firings, yes it makes sense since all we care about is the first non-duplicate one. And if [1] is going to work, I dont want to go through [3]. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

I tried out this solution at a larger scale and as long as I provide sufficient workers and disks, the pipeline scales well although I am seeing a different problem now.

After this sessionization, I run a `Combine.perKey` on the key and then perform a `ParDo` which looks into `c.pane().getTiming()` and only rejects anything other than an `EARLY` firing. I tried counting both `EARLY` and `ONTIME` firings in this `ParDo` and it looks like the ontime-panes are actually deduped more precisely than the early ones. I mean, the #early-firings still has some duplicates whereas the #ontime-firings is less than that and has more duplicates removed. Is there any reason this could happen? Also, is my approach towards deduping using a `Combine+ParDo` the right one or could I do something better?

```
events.apply(
    WithKeys.<String, EventInfo>of(new SerializableFunction<EventInfo, String>() {
        @Override
        public java.lang.String apply(EventInfo input) {
            return input.getUniqueKey();
        }
    })
)
.apply(
    Window.named("sessioner").<KV<String, EventInfo>>into(
        Sessions.withGapDuration(mSessionGap)
    )
    .triggering(
        AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
        .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))
    )
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
    .accumulatingFiredPanes()
);
```